# CSS: Why does the absolute div does not expand in height to fit text?

Tags: html, css

Would be helpful if someone can shed some light on the fact as to why in the following case the div "sitecontainer" does not expand automatically to accomodate the nested sample text inside it? Even after setting the height to : auto. To understand what I am saying, kindly please post any copied text exceeding more than a standard html page length (preferably two) in the div "sitecontainer" (third line of html code below). Here is the image below : (please note that the "sitecontainer" div (the one in green) ends in between when I scroll the page down)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IinsH.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
CSS:

<style>
body {
margin: auto;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
overflow: auto;
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.sitecontainer {
background-color: rgba(0,255,51,1);
width: 75%;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
height: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
display: block;
color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
overflow: visible;
float: left;
clear: both;
}
</style>
```

HTML :

```
<body>
<div class="sitecontainer">
<-- PLEASE POST ANY TEXT HERE THAT EXCEEDS A NORMAL PAGE LENGTH-->>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all. Is that your exactly html? Cause the comment has two ">>" at the end. And also, it should be: <!-- --> 

// I'll take a look to your code.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zduwun5/1/)

Your problem is on .sitecontainer's CSS. You are' setting "top: 0; bottom: 0;" so it will take viewport's height. Check the fiddle

```
.sitecontainer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 51, 1);
  width: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given the css property top:0px and bottom:0px so in the responsive design the browser will take the height of the view port automatically.so whenever the site is open on any device that will take the height according to the browser window.